# I am trying to select all the values from a table using date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to select all the values from a table using date in SQL Server 2008. The problem is the `date` column in the DB is in `Datetime` format. But the thing is I have to select all the values from the database by using date

I used the following query

```
select * 
from Table 
where subdate = '2012-12-12'.
```

It won't return any value....

My table is like this

```
Subdate                        val1    val2    val3 name
--------------                -----   -----   ----  -----
2012-12-12 12:32:12.000     2   1   2    ben
2012-12-27 15:17:32.533     2   1   2    yen
2012-12-27 15:20:06.660     2   1   2    sun
```

Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from Tble where subdate>='20121212' and subdate <'20121213'
```

would be my usual recommended approach(*). If it's a parameter, it would be:

```
select * from Tble where subdate>=@Parm and subdate <DATEADD(day,1,@Parm)
```

---

`'2012-12-12'` and `'2012/12/12'` can be subject to weird conversion issues, depending on your language/date settings on the server. `'20121212'` will always be converted as `YYYYMMDD`.

---

(*) I don't use `BETWEEN` for such comparisons, because you either include two midnights , or you have to calculate the last moment before midnight of the following day. Which would be at `23:59:59.997` if you're using `datetime`, but suddenly changes to being something else for `datetime2`.

Comment: @user1879556 - if you're typing it in as a literal in a query window, just avoid including any separator characters. If you're passing a parameter, you ought to pass it as a `datetime` parameter rather than `varchar`, and then any necessary conversions happen automatically. If it's not one of those two, I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE CAST(subdate AS DATE)='2012-12-12'
```

Raj

Comment: Hi raj...I executed the query but it throws the following error as Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: Oh OK. When I saw SQL 2008, I assumed you have SQL 2008 R2. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Raj - 2008 (not R2) has `date` as well. I'd guess the DB is running at a lower compatibility level.

Comment: @user1879556: try running `SELECT @@Version` - what does that tell you? Are you **really*** on a **2008** version?? I suspect you're not - SQL Server 2008 **does have** the `DATE` datatype....

Comment: Version is...Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.1399.06 (Intel X86)   Oct 14 2005 00:33:37   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Comment: sql server installed in my system is 2008 r2.....But i have connected to a remote server...

Answer (score 1):

The date in the table also contain `Time` so you have to convert that date to the format suitable for the date you enter.

You have to use:  [Sql Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

```
select * from Tble where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), subdate, 111) = '2012/12/12'
```

### Demo [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea023/6)